# How Do We Get a Looper from an Executor?

Tags: android

Google's documentation on bound services is promoting [using a `Messenger` in lieu of your own custom binding for IPC](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger). So, I am giving that a try for [a particular experiment that I am running](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/03/27/peek-surfacecontrolviewhost-android-r.html).

However, a `Messenger` needs a `Handler`. Nowadays, a `Handler` needs a `Looper`, and I might want one in this scenario for a background thread anyway (as opposed to `Looper.getMainLooper()`). The only other `Looper` that I know how to get is to `run()` a `HandlerThread` and get a `Looper` from it.

The documentation for [the deprecated non-`Looper` forms of the `Handler` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler()) have:

> Implicitly choosing a Looper during Handler construction can lead to bugs where operations are silently lost (if the Handler is not expecting new tasks and quits), crashes (if a handler is sometimes created on a thread without a Looper active), or race conditions, where the thread a handler is associated with is not what the author anticipated. **Instead, use an Executor or specify the Looper explicitly, using Looper#getMainLooper, View#getHandler, or similar.**

(emphasis added)

Is this just strangely-worded documentation, or if there is a recipe for getting a `Looper` or `Handler` tied to an `Executor` that I cannot seem to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: TL;DR

```kotlin
// Check if this thread already has prepared a looper
if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
    Looper.prepare()
}
val threadHandler = Handler(Looper.myLooper())
val messenger = Messenger(threadHandler)
messenger.send(...)
```

**Long Answer**

If you want to dig a little bit more on what's going on and in which thread is every piece of code running:

```kotlin
// Check if this thread already has prepared a looper
// Running on Original Thread
if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
    Looper.prepare()
}
// Save thread's Looper (1)
// Running on Original Thread
val threadLooper = Looper.myLooper()
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    // Do some UI stuff, for instance, show a dialog
    // Running on UI Thread
    AlertDialog
        .Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Dialog title")
        .setMessage("Dialog message")
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            // Use thread's Looper from (1) to notify the original thread
            // Running on UI Thread
            Handler(threadLooper).post {
                // Running on Original Thread
                callback?.onCancel()
            }
        }
        .setPositiveButton("Retry") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            // Use thread's Looper from (1) to notify the original thread
            // Running on UI Thread
            Handler(threadLooper).post {
                // Running on Original Thread
                callback?.onRetry()
            }
        }
        .show()
}
// Call loop() to start the thread's loop
// Running on Original Thread
Looper.loop()
```

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the question.

Comment: The question is "How Do We Get a Looper from an Executor?". I think this clearly answer the question, right?

Comment: I do not see an `Executor` in your answer.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly know your executor since this is using the thread data. Have you tried it?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean, and I will see if I can work something out with this. The problem that I ran into is that you have a bunch of code, with no explanation. Most of the code is unrelated to the question (creating an `AlertDialog`), and nothing in the code is obviously tied to the `Executor` that is the central point of the question. So, I disagree that it "clearly answer the question", though your second comment (and a couple of the lines in the answer) gave me a direction to pursue. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I'll make an edit to clarify, I just wanted to give more context on in which thread each part of the code was executing

Comment: The problem I see with what you propose here is that your `Looper`-related code has to be running on the background thread. That's because `Looper` is relying on a `ThreadLocal` to have static data that is per-thread. With an `Executor`, all you can do is schedule a `Runnable` to be executed. That `Runnable` could set up the `Looper` and call `loop()`... but that now messes up the `Executor`, which is expecting the `Runnable` to return normally, and `loop()` blocks until the `Looper` is `quit()`. Technically, you could probably still do it this way, which is why I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean to suggest to use an `Executor` instead of a `Handler`. I don't know of any `Executor` implementation backed by a `Looper`.

> Instead [of a `Handler`], use an `Executor` or specify the `Looper` explicitly, using `Looper#getMainLooper`, `View#getHandler`, or similar.

This is useful when you only need to run a `Runable`. For example the [CameraManager.openCamera()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#openCamera(java.lang.String,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback)) method got an overload with the API level 28.

> The behavior of this method matches that of `openCamera(java.lang.String, StateCallback, android.os.Handler)`, except that it uses `Executor` as an argument instead of `Handler`.

If you require a `Messenger`, you'll always have to provide a `Hanlder` backed by a `Looper`, which was resolved by `Looper.getMainLooper()`, `Looper.myLooper()` or from a `HandlerThread`.

Alternatively you could create a `Looper` and run [`loop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Looper#loop()) on it. But this is basically what a `HandlerThread` does.

Comment: "I think they mean to suggest to use an Executor instead of a Handler" -- is there a way to use an `Executor` with a `Messenger`? IOW, why are they bringing up `Executor` at all here?

Comment: I've added an example. It's an API replacing the usage of a `Handler` with an `Executor`. With a `Messenger` you won't be able to use an `Executor` though.

Comment: I am accepting the other answer, as in theory you could use it to hack an `Executor` to offer a `Looper`. I am granting you the bounty as I think this is really just poorly-written on Google's part and that they mean that you might use `Executor` instead of any `Looper`/`Handler` stuff.

Comment: Just keep in mind that an `Executor` is an abstraction and the `Thread` could be any random. So when you start a `Looper` in it, you might break the `Executor`. Also you'll have to manage the queue yourself and ensure to call `quit` on it.